# python table view output

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have some thing like this in output.txt file

```
Service1:Aborted
Service2:failed
Service3:failed
Service4:Aborted
Service5:failed
```

output in 2nd file(output2.txt) :

```
 Service1        Service2   Servive3   Service4     Service5
 Aborted         failed     failed     Aborted      failed
```

Would like to get output in table format as above

Code I am trying:

```
    file=open('output.txt','r')
    target=open('output2.txt','w')
    states=[]
    for line in file.readlines():
         parts=line.strip().split(':')
         states.append(parts[1].strip())
   target.write(','.join(states))        
   target.close()
```

Comment: remove what comma ?? The files in your post don't have any commas

Comment: sorry i did edit the question. @coder

Comment: Still there are no commas in output.txt nor in output2.txt

Comment: `var2=part.strip()+","`: shouldn't it be `var2+=...` And anyway all this could be replaced by `var2 = ",".join(part)`. No need for rstrip!

Comment: yup sorry for the confusion, I am looking to get the output in the table format. @ElmoVanKielmo

Comment: did edit my code @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very quickly:

```
headers = []
statuses = []

for line in file:
    line=line.strip()
    parts=line.split(":")
    headers.append(parts[0])
    statuses.append(parts[1])

format_str = '{:>15}'*(len(headers))

print(format_str.format(*headers))
print(format_str.format(*statuses))
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to remove spaces between each words and add a comma (,) ? @adgon32

Comment: If you'd like to completely remove spaces, you just had to remove formatting. `','.join(headers)` and `','.join(statuses)` should work for you @sdrockzz .

Answer (score 0):

You're on your own for figuring out how to get your input data into a numpy array, and what example the reshape function does, but this should get you about 75% to the finish line

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A_in = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
B = pd.DataFrame(np.array(A_in).reshape(3,2))
B.to_csv('output2.txt,'\t')
```